# Git: How to remove merged commit from history messages?

Tags: git, merge

My workflow goes like this:

- Create a new branch X.
- Do some commits
- Checkout to master
- Merge X into master

But then my history looks like this:

```
commit c37c0b495e6cede93dd359201e14af46f7d4bbaf
Merge: 93f526c e72b831
Author: ...
Date:   Mon Dec 2 10:29:13 2013 +0200

    Merge branch 'X'

commit e72b831f8b2d78ac6650190f062dfd1065551f64
Author: ...
Date:   Mon Dec 2 10:28:45 2013 +0200

    The new features that X introduced.
```

My question is how do I get rid of the Merge branch 'X' message in my history so I can push the commits from branch X to the upstream repository and not mess up the history there?

Thanks

Comment: Consider not trying to remove branch X and leaving all as it is. I actually think that what you are trying to do is against good practice.

Comment: @ijkilchenko What do you mean by not trying to remove branch X? I'm new to git and I was left with the impression that I should create a new branch for every new feature and after the feature is complete I'm supposed to merge the feature into the master repo and then push it to the remote, no?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question (I read it before it was edited). I thought you were trying to get rid of branch X entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rebase before merging.

My workflow:

- Create a new branch X.
- Do some commits
- Rebase against master
- Checkout to master
- Merge X into master

Comment: What does it mean to rebase against master? Pull new commits from master into branch X that have been made while whoever has been working on branch X?

Comment: Yes. You can check [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) for more information. I guess that the OP gets the merge commit because his merging is not straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

A merge commit doesn't "mess up the branch", but if you'd like to avoid the merge commit try [rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) instead.

I.e. instead of merging your commits from `X` to `master`, you rebase `X` on top of `master` which effectively "replays" your commits and thus integrates the changes without needing a merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have this "Merge Branch" (which is called a merge commit) you need to **rebase** your commits into the `master`.

You can do this in two steps:

1.) If your `master` is **not** up to date with the `origin/master`, you have to do the following before you go to step 2

```
git fetch
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
```

2.) If your `master` **is** up to date with the `origin/master`, do the following:

```
git rebase master X
git checkout master
git merge X
git push
```

This way you don't get the merge commit you are talking about.

**UPDATE after someone added a comment**:

`git rebase --onto` is documented [Git - Rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/ch3-6.html).
It basically does the following. Given the following git history:

```
hash1 (master origin/master)
  |  
hash2 (X origin/X)
hash3 commit3
hash4 commit4
hash5 commit5  
   | /
hash6 commit6
```

If you execute

```
git rebase --onto master commit5 X
```

then Git takes everything between `commit5` (exclusive) and `X` (inclusive) and moves it on op of `master`, so it will look like this:

```
hash2 X
hash3 commit3
hash4 commit4
hash1 (master origin/master)
  |  
hash2 (origin/X)
hash3 commit3
hash4 commit4
hash5 commit5  
   | /
hash6 commit6
```

As you can see, the `X` is not 3 commits ahead of `master` and the `origin/X` is still on it's "old" place.

If you don't have an `origin/X`, the branch disappears (because it has moved). But if you want your `origin/X` to "move" to `X`, you have to push this one particular branch

```
git push --force origin X
```

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation! The only thing that I didn't understand is what is "--onto master Y X" is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all here's the [reference link](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merging) I'll be using

When git has 2 branches and wants to merge them, it creates a new commit called a `merge commit` this commit introduces the diff of both trees since the common parent 
[image: figure 3-17]

*@figure 3-17 in the [reference link](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merging)*

The only time when a merge doesn't create a merge commit is when the merge is a fast-forward merge

[image: Figure 3-12]

*@figure 3-12 [reference link](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merging)*

So the only option to avoid a merge commit is to [rebase first](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as everybody said you can use rebase, but I would not recommend that. If you follow workflow where each branch represents new feature and you want to be able to read history and understand from which branch those changes came, you should keep those merge messages. The only thing that I would recommend: use rebase strategy during git pull.